# Importing a local JSON file Javascript with XMLHttpRequest() type issues

Tags: javascript

I need to switch from an API to a local JSON file. To import, I'm using:

```
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.overrideMimeType("application/json");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
          if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "200") {
                   dates = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
          }
    };
    xhr.open('GET', '../dates.json', true); // local vesrion of data
    xhr.send(null);
```

However, it imports differently than the API version and won't parse the same. 
Sample data:

```
{"datesold":"2016-01-01T06:00:00"}
{"datesold":"2016-01-02T06:00:00"}
{"datesold":"2016-01-02T06:00:00"}
{"datesold":"2016-01-03T06:00:00"}
{"datesold":"2016-01-04T06:00:00"}
{"datesold":"2016-01-04T06:00:00"}
```

It comes in as an array of strings with the api call:

```
["2016-01-01T06:00:00","2016-01-02T06:00:00",
"2016-01-03T06:00:00","2016-01-04T06:00:00",
"2016-01-05T06:00:00","2016-01-06T06:00:00"]
```

how can I transform the data to match the return form my API call?

Comment: are the {datasold: ...} objects in an array?

Comment: They are not. I could just put them in brackets but they would not be comma separated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `map` of `Array.prototype`. See below code.

```js
var x=["2016-01-01T06:00:00","2016-01-02T06:00:00",
"2016-01-03T06:00:00","2016-01-04T06:00:00",
"2016-01-05T06:00:00","2016-01-06T06:00:00"];

y=x.map(function(x){
    return {"datesold":x}
    });
console.log(y);
//y.forEach(x=>console.log(typeof x));
```

Comment: Thanks but that is mapping the array of strings not the objects.

Comment: @TravisClark sorry didn't get you? it is mapping array of objects. just uncomment the last line(which i added) and you will see

Comment: It doesn't work with the data I have coming in. It's x needs to = the objects like this: 

    var x=[{"datesold":"2016-01-01T06:00:00"}
{"datesold":"2016-01-02T06:00:00"}
{"datesold":"2016-01-02T06:00:00"}
{"datesold":"2016-01-03T06:00:00"}
{"datesold":"2016-01-04T06:00:00"}
{"datesold":"2016-01-04T06:00:00"}];

Comment: @TravisClark means you want reverse from what I have done.

Answer (score 0):

You can map it if it's an array:

```
var transormedArray = DataArray.map((obj) => {
  return obj.datasold;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a great answer but it's the best I could come up with so far.

```
let json = JSON.stringify(xhr.responseText);
step1 = json.replace(/[\"datesold:\"]/g,'');
step2 = step1.replace(/[\n\\]/g,'');
step3 = step2.replace(/[{}]/g, '');
dates = step3.split("\n");
```